# How can I approve an edit to $\LaTeX$ when the preview is not shown?

Tags: feature-request

I was just presented with a suggested edit to my $\LaTeX$ code, but the preview was not shown. Thus, it was not easy for me to check that the code would render properly and what it would look like (also seeing as I did not recognise the environment that the editor used). I just had to accept it in blind faith that it would turn out okay. I think the preview needs to be shown, the reason for which is obvious in this case. I haven't been on Math.SE for a while, so I can't remember how the suggested edits are presented there.

I'm using Chrome on 9.7" Android tablet.

[image: I can't see the LaTeX rendering]

Comment: As fun of a feature this would be, probably the way to go about it for now is to copy paste the suggested changes (minus the strikeout text) and then edit the actual post and see how it would look that way (which thinking about it now is a rather cumbersome thing to do).